# php does not echo anything from ajax javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot get my input to be echo when I input text in my search field.
I do get the alert javascript but not the echo 2 to be display into the `srv_search_mini_display` field. 
Im thinking that the ajax cant access the `find_Service.php`

search.php

```
 <input id="service_search_box" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Services..." oninput="searchService()">
 <div id="service_search_div" class="srv_search_mini_display d-none"></div>

<script type="application/javascript">

function searchService(){

    var srv_search = document.getElementById("service_search_box").value;

    var param = "service_search_box="+srv_search;

    if(srv_search.length > 0){

        $("#search_search_div").removeClass("d-none");

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){

                if(ajax.responseText === ""){

                    document.getElementById("service_search_div").innerHTML = "";
                    $("#service_search_div").addClass("d-none");

                } else {

                    alert(param); document.getElementById("service_search_div").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }

            }
        };

        ajax.open("POST",'find_Service.php',false);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send(param);

    } else{

        document.getElementById("service_search_div").innerHTML = "";
        $("#service_search_div").addClass("d-none");
    }

}
</script>
```

find_Service.php

```
 <?php

 require_once('database.php');
 $heidisql = pdo_con();

 echo 2; // does not even appear
  ?>
```

Comment: "_echo 2; // does not even appear_" Where should that appear?

Comment: inside the `<div id="service_search_div" class="srv_search_mini_display d-none"></div>`

Comment: 1) " Im thinking that the ajax cant access the find_Service.php" ...you can easily check this by watching your browser's Network tools (inside the developer tools) and/or by stepping through the code with your JavaScript debugger (also in the developer tools). Have you done that yet?

Comment: ```document.getElementById("service_search_div").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;``` why this in the comment section. it should be in the next line to set the HTML.

Comment: 2) "2" does not appear anywhere because you never tell the JavaScript to make it appear. Try `if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){ document.getElementById("service_search_div").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;` or similar. Right now, your code checks for an empty response, and then sets the div empty. But it never tries to use the response if there is one. It's true you have written `document.getElementById("service_search_div").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;` already...but you left it inside a comment so it will never be executed!!

Comment: Sorry the comment was only for the alert part. Also I just did what u asked and still nothing appear.

Comment: echo  before  require_once('database.php');  and check whether it is displaying or not.

Comment: also did that no response

Comment: Enable error_reporting in 'find_Service.php' and check.  If you run the find_Service.php separately in browser is it echoing '2' have you checked that

Comment: yep the 2 is being echo when i try it on separately in browser. Im not getting any error

Comment: Have you checked in browser console. Does it display any error related to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make sure that your PHP file work, you can check it by open `find_Service.php` separately or like @ADyson said check it from inspect console in network tab.

Since I saw you using jQuery, I simplify your code a little bit by using jQuery's ajax and select element with `$` sign.

*I use fake API server to make it work here.*

```js
function searchService(){
  var srv_search = $('#service_search_box').val();
  var $srv_search_div = $('#service_search_div');

  if(srv_search.length > 0){
    $("#search_search_div").removeClass("d-none");

    $.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", //replace with "/find_Service.php"
    {
      service_search_box: srv_search,
    },
    function(data, status){
      if(status === "success" ){
        $srv_search_div.html(data.service_search_box); //replace with data
        $srv_search_div.addClass("d-none");
      }
      console.log(data);
    });

  }else{
    $srv_search_div.html("");
    $("#service_search_div").addClass("d-none");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="service_search_box" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Services..." oninput="searchService()">
 <div id="service_search_div" class="srv_search_mini_display d-none"></div>
```

Comment: ok i manage to get the 2 appear in console, but still nothing appear in the div

Comment: if you use my code change `$srv_search_div.html(data.service_search_box);` to `$srv_search_div.html(data);`